# Integrate CPLEX solver into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell, command-line, cplex

I am writing Linear Programming solution using VBA and solving it by CPLEX solver. I can connect these steps manually by writing LP file by VBA, solve in CPLEX, write out solution and read that solution by another subroutine of VBA for further processing. However, my new study need to repeat these steps many times, which is writing LP file, solved by CPLEX, write solution, process solution by VBA to release new LP file, then  solved by CPLEX and so on. 
3 commands I need to type in CPLEX each times it is called are:

```
Read (name).lp
Optimize
write (name).sol
```

I have tried shell function:

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
wsh.Run "C:\cplex.exe /S /K read 1.lp", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

This code can call cplex but cannot implement the command (however, it works well for other executable files like cmd.exe). Could anyone help me to sort this trouble? Any ideas is greatly appreciated, even suggest me to use another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure if you can use it from VBA, but why not just use the CPLEX .Net API which is accessible from VB?

There are lots of examples (e.g. in C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\examples\src\vb) that show how to use the API.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a good solution. A tiny problem is that I need to convert all my code in VBA into VB. 
I have found another solution, which is use SendInput module (http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/). I can call CPLEX and pass command into it, but that CPLEX cannot recognise any data files located same folder (e.g., read lp file but other commands like display, help etc. work normally). However, when I run CPLEX.exe directly (i.e. double click on it), it still works well. Do you know how to solve it.

Comment: Maybe try using a full path to the file - it may be that CPLEX is defaulting to its own local folder where the cplex.exe is stored?